# move_uploaded_file not writing when attempting to overwrite

Tags: php, html

I'm attempting to create a webpage that will accept a CSV file eventually upload it to a database, however I'm currently stuck on getting it to overwrite itself, if another file with the same name exists. Currently I have the following:

index.html -

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select CSV file to upload
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" accept=".csv">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
    </form>
```

upload.php -

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    function print_array($array)
    {
        //---//
        //print out an array in a way that doesn't make you want to vommit.
        //---//
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array);
        echo "</pre><p>";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['overwrite_YES']))
    {
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] = $_POST['name'];
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'] = $_POST['type'];
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] = $_POST['tmp_name'];
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] = $_POST['error'];
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] = $_POST['size'];
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] = str_replace("/","\\",$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);

        $target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $fileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        print_array($_FILES);
        if (!file_exists($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']))
        {
            echo "tmp file does not exists.<br>";
        }
        echo "fileToUpload: " . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] . " -> " . $target_file . "<br>";
        //unlink($target_file);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
        {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "womp womp :(";
        }
        exit;
    }

    else if(isset($_POST['overwrite_NO']))
    {
        $temp_name = $_POST['temp_name'];
        unlink($temp_name);
        echo "upload cancelled.<br>";
        exit;
    }


    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $fileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);



    if($fileType != "csv" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only CSV files are allowed. ";
    }
    else 
    {
        if (file_exists($target_file))
        {
            print_array($_FILES);
            $temp_name = "D:/xampp/tmp/ASMTMP.tmp";
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $temp_name);

            echo "the file '" . $target_file . "' already exists.<br>";
            echo "would you like to overwrite this?<br>";
            echo "<form id='overwrite' action=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . " method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='" . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] . "' />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='type' value='" . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'] . "' />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='tmp_name' value='" . $temp_name . "' />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='error' value='" . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] . "' />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='size' value='" . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] . "' />";
            echo "<input name='overwrite_YES' style='height:40; width:150;' type='submit' value='Yes' />";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "<form id='nooverwrite' action=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . " method='post'>";
            echo "<input name='overwrite_NO' style='height:40; width:150;' type='submit' value='No' />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='temp_name' value='" . $temp_name . "' />";
            echo "</form>";


        }
        else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
        {
            print_array($_FILES);
            echo "fileToUpload: " . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] . " -> " . $target_file . "<br>";
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

So everything is working correctly when I go through this except for the one line that reads 'womp womp :('.
If the file doesn't exist. It writes correctly. If the file does exist, it writes the temp file correctly, but when I try to actually overwrite the existing file the if (move_uploaded_file ...) skips and goes down to the else statement.

The output for a successful write looks like:

```
    Array
    (
        [fileToUpload] => Array
            (
                [name] => test.csv
                [type] => application/octet-stream
                [tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\phpFEE0.tmp
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 488007
            )

    )
    fileToUpload: D:\xampp\tmp\phpFEE0.tmp -> uploads/test.csv
    The file test.csv has been uploaded.
```

The output for a failed overwrite looks like:

```
    Array
    (
        [fileToUpload] => Array
            (
                [name] => test.csv
                [type] => application/octet-stream
                [tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\ASMTMP.tmp
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 488007
            )
    )
    fileToUpload: D:\xampp\tmp\ASMTMP.tmp -> uploads/test.csv
    womp womp :(
```

I've attempted to use unlink right before the overwrite to make sure it wasn't having an issue with the actual overwrite, but that didn't help. And I'm not getting any errors, so any help with this is very appreciated.

Comment: There's 3 total lines containing 'move_uploaded_file()' in them. each of those lines 'should' only be executing if and only if the other two lines are not being executed.

Comment: Sorry, actually the one which I'm having problems with 'does' run after another one runs, but I would assume that it wouldn't cause an issue since they're using different files.

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file
is running after
$temp_name = "D:/xampp/tmp/ASMTMP.tmp";
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $temp_name);

I'm re-writing the tmp file to something that will stick around after the POST, then I'll delete it after I'm done with it. Could that be the issue maybe?

and

Comment: `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] = str_replace("/","\\",$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);` why???

Answer (score 1):

In the end I changed

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)
...

to

if (rename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
...

which resolved the issue I was having, in case anyone else runs into this. I 'think' maybe the issue was possibly because 'move_uploaded_file' wouldn't work because I had created a new tmp file? and I think it didn't like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwritting the values of your $_FILES variable.

**Remove these lines:**

```
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] = $_POST['name'];
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'] = $_POST['type'];
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] = $_POST['tmp_name'];
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] = $_POST['error'];
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] = $_POST['size'];
        $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] = str_replace("/","\\",$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: So when I first made this page, the $_FILE array wasn't being transferred once you pressed 'yes' or 'no'. So I saved the data by sending it via $_POST.

Then re-writing it back to the $_FILES array once it was there. I'm writing the $_FILES array again once it's at that point to make sure it getting in there correctly, if you look at the failed output. the $_FILES array is being written to the screen and it looks correct.

Comment: If that is the case, then don't overwrite `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']` - just remove line  `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] = $_POST['tmp_name'];`

Comment: Or else it will fail.

Comment: So for that part I'm saving the tmp file as well. if you look above that part: 

$temp_name = "D:/xampp/tmp/ASMTMP.tmp";
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $temp_name);

when I press 'yes' or 'no' the temp file was disappearing along with the $_FILES array. So all I'm doing is making my own tmp file called ASMTMP.tmp and moving the old tmp file into it, so that it gets saved longer than the actual tmp file.

Comment: and I've checked that new file 'ASMTMP.tmp' and it looks correct, however that file will not be moved. Possibly there are permission issues on that tmp file? I'm going to try that and see if that works.

Comment: As soon as your file is uploaded successfully, its temp file is deleted. You cannot reuse it.

Comment: That's why I'm creating my own seperate tmp file that I can save, then re-write the existing file with it, then delete the new tmp file that I created.
also adding chmod($temp_name,0777); did not appear to work : /
I also tried making my custom tmp file into a .csv just to see, that's not working either though.